# Obtaining the name field from one table based on the DataID from another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm tasked with writing a report in SQL Server with the following fields:

```
HoldName, HoldDataID, ActiveHold, DtreeAncestors.Id, DtreeAncestors.Name, 
Collections.ID, Collections.Name
```

I was able to figure everything out except for the name fields for DtreeAncestors and Collections.

I have the following tables:

Table 1

```
DtreeCore.DataID       
DtreeCore.Name
```

Table 2

```
RM_ObjectHold.NodeID
RM_ObjectHold.ActiveHold
```

Table 3

```
DtreeAncestor.DataID
```

Table 4

```
Collections.DataID
```

The name fields for all objects are in the DTreeCore table. I mapped the `RM_ObjectHold.NodeID` to its name in the DtreeCore table but I don't know how to do the same for Dtreeancestor and Collections?

This is my SQL statement so far:

```
Select
    DtreeCore.Name,
    DtreeCore.DataID,
    DTreeAncestors.AncestorID,
    RM_ObjectHold.Activehold,
    Collections.CollectionID
from 
    RM_ObjectHold
Join 
    DtreeCore on RM_ObjectHold.NodeID = DtreeCore.DataID
join 
    DTreeAncestors on DTreeAncestors.DataID = RM_ObjectHold.NodeID
join 
    Collections on Collections.DataID = DtreeCore.DataID
```

Let me know if you need any other info or clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What does *"the name fields for DtreeAncestors and Collections."* mean? What does *"The name fields for all objects are in the DTreeCore table"* mean? Sounds like you got some foreign keys here, but you haven't said what they are, or what exactly you want out of your query

Comment: DtreeAncestor and Collections have names stored in the DtreeCore table.  I need to extract the names of DtreeAncestor and Collections columns.  I don't think any of these tables have  foreign keys. Thank you

Comment: If they have no foreign keys then your guess is much better than ours, you have the data in front of you and can see what might be a likely join. I would imagine you would need to join `DtreeCore` multiple times though, once for each of the other tables